# PNG image color doesn't change in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using below code to change color of a PNG image on canvas dynamically,

```
var selectedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

if ("text" == selectedObject.type) {
   selectedObject.setFill("#FF0000");
   canvas.renderAll();
}
else {    
  selectedObject.filters.push(
    new fabric.Image.filters.Tint({color:"#FF0000", opacity:0.6}));

  selectedObject.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}
```

Where `canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');`

*Static colors are added for testing purpose which will be replaced by colorpicker.

For text it is working fine but for image it is not working.

Comment: @Tushar Gupta please check here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/93xje/3/, when we select text color changes but when we select image no effect i want to change color of png image as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply image filters on crossOrigin images. If you look at developer console you see the following security error: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Please use only images from same origin or use latest Fabric.js version (dev version) and set `crossOrigin = "Anonymous"`. In this case the image have to be served with the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *".

You use the new API of `fabric.Image.filters.Tint` - this API is only available in Fabric.js versions >= 1.3.2.

I've updated the jsfiddle to use data-URL images (no problem with CORS) and update Fabric.js to 1.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/wDfhf/

You can find the latest dev version (by your own risk:)) at https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tree/master/dist

Comment: Kienz, I cannot (as of now) upgrade to a more recent version of fabric.js (we are using 1.2.0). Is there a way to get the crossOrigin stuff working in that version? I tried adding `img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';` in the loadImage function and was not successful.

Comment: Based on the 1.4.7 code, it looks like you need to use setCrossOrigin [ https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/492253e5cac12fce41ad667f393b7f7443b124e0/src/shapes/image.class.js#L96 ], but I can't get it to work in Chrome.

Comment: @Jack You have to pass the crossOrigin property into the loadImage function. The crossOrigin property have to be set before the image loading process begins.
fabric.util.loadImage('xyz.png', function(img) {
  ...
}, null, 'anonymous'});

Comment: @Kienz we actually got it working a while ago, (we ended up upgrading fabric).

Comment: @Jack Can you please help me on that. The canvas images are loading from cross origin but i still cannot apply filters